# Codeigniter 3 pagination links and single post link throw 404

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have read other articles on this from here but could not solve this problem. My problems are 2.

1. Pagination shows but clicking links of pagination generates 404.
2. I have list of articles in db that are being displayed but when I
   click single article link for single article page, it shows 404.

I am on localhost wamp. Here is my code. The commented code is what I have been trying but did not work for me.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'not_found';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['articles/(:any)'] = 'articles/$1';
//$route['articles'] = 'articles';
```

**config / baseurl**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/practice/project-code-igniter/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**Controller - Articles.php**

```
class Articles extends CI_Controller {

public function index($start=0)
{
    // $this->output->cache('86400');
    $this->load->view('header');
    //load model
    // $this->load->model('articles_model');
    // load 'get_articles' function from 'articles_model' model and store it in data

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $data['articles']=$this->articles_model->get_articles(5,$start);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('articles')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 2; //NUMBER OF LINKS BEFORE AND AFTER CURRENT PAGE IF ON PAGE ONE WILL SHOW 4 PAGES AFTERWARDS IF YOU HAVE ENOUGH RESULTS TO FILL THAT MANY

    //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = "&lt;&lt; First";
    $config['last_link'] = "Last &gt;&gt;";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    //$data['pages'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    //$page = ($this->uri->segment(3))? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    // //call the model function to get the department data
    //$data['pages'] = $this->articles_model->get_articles($config["per_page"], $data['page']);
    $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    //$this->load->view('page_articles');
    // load view and load model data with it 
    $this->load->view('page_articles',$data);

    $this->load->view('footer');
}


// single article
// function post($perma){
//  $this->load->view('header');
//  $this->load->model('articles_model');
//  $data['articles']=$this->articles_model->get_single_article($perma);
//  $this->load->view('page_article',$data);
//  $this->load->view('footer');
// }
}
```

**Model / Articles_model**

```
class Articles_model extends CI_Model {

// function get_articles() {
public function get_articles($limit, $start) {

    // $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM articles");
    // $this->db->select()->from('articles');
    // $this->db->select()->from('articles')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit(0,20);

    $this->db->select()->from('articles')->where('status','1')->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    // return object
    // return $query->result();
    // return array
    return $query->result_array();

}

function get_articles_count(){
    $this->db->select('id')->from('articles')->where('status',1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}



// for single article
// function get_single_article($perma){
//  $this->db->select()->from('articles')->where(array('status'=>1,'permalink'=>$perma));
//  $query = $this->db->get();
//  return $query->first_row('array');
// }


}
```

**View / page_articles**

```
<?php
if(!isset($articles)) { ?> <div class="alert alert-info">No records</div> <?php } else 
{ 

  ?>

      <ol>
          <?php 
          foreach($articles as $row) 
          { ?>

                <li>
                    <h4><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>articles/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>/<?php echo $row['permalink']; ?>/">
                        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                    </a></h4>
                    <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($row['detail']),0,100).".."; ?>
                    <br>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>articles/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>/<?php echo $row['permalink']; ?>/">Read more</a>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                </li>

          <?php } ?>
      </ol>

      <?php
}
?>
</p>

<div>
    <?php echo $pages; ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: "does not work" is not very helpful to anyone.  Did you do any troubleshooting?  Have you inspected the rendered links?  Are the links constructed correctly?

Comment: Yep! all that. Its my first attempt to MVC and its been 2 days i am stuck with this same 2 problems. Reading tutorials but could not figure out, yet. The commented code is the research/failed attempts in progress.

Comment: I can't even follow what you've done.  If `$start` (`offset`) is supposed to represent the page number, then your `offset` cannot be this same number.  If you want `5` results per page, then the `offset` for page 3 would not be `3`... it would be `10`.

Comment: That is the problem. I have watched video tutorials and read articles and tried stuff and now its mixed up.

Comment: I have 'CodeIgniter Essentials', 'Code Igniter Best Practices', 'Build a CMS in CodeIgniter' by TutsPlus and by watching these I was able to setup pages and system setup and configuration. I have retrieved data from db but the pagination and single record need good concepts that need more time and practice may be.

Comment: We cannot effectively solve this without knowing what the ***desired*** paginated URL is supposed to look like.  Although my answer identifies two areas where you have some mistakes and/or mismatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem...

```
public function index($start=0)
```

you seem to use `$start` for your page number and again for your `offset` value...

```
$data['articles']=$this->articles_model->get_articles(5,$start);
```

If `$start` is representing your page number, then you cannot also use it for your `offset` value.

Your offset needs to be calculated...

```
$offset = ($start - 1) * 5;
$data['articles']=$this->articles_model->get_articles(5, $offset);
```

Example:

With 5 records per page, page 4 would start with record #16.  So `15` is the correct `offset` to get records #16, 17, 18, 19, & 20 for page 4.

---

Another potential issue...

```
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
```

You've set the page number as segment 3, but your route is showing the page number at segment 2...

```
$route['articles/(:any)'] = 'articles/$1';
```

It also does not match this setting, which would also put your page number at segment 2...

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/';
```

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578320/codeigniter-3-pagination-links-and-single-post-link-throw-404/38579146?noredirect=1#comment64547565_38579146),

> waow. What I did just now... I changed `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/';` to `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/index/';` and the pagination links show the page now but records are not changing. The 404 goes away and page is changing - records are first 5 on all pages....

then the route should be this...

```
$route['articles/index/(:any)'] = 'articles/$1';
```

So it matches the new `base_url` you describe...

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/index/';
```

Comment: waow. What I did just now... I changed $config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/'; to $config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/index/'; and the pagination links show the page now but records are not changing. The 404 goes away and page is changing - records are first 5 on all pages....

Comment: @HiroshiRana, so then look at the rest of my answer! Your `offset` value is not being used if every page has the same number of records.  That's probably because your route is still only routing from the second segment.

Comment: Your answer did not help much.

Comment: @HiroshiRana, if you still don't understand how my answer shows your mistakes, then simply ask for specific clarification.  Please do not get demanding or complain.  People here are only trying to help, while you are expected to construct a question that contains everything needed in order to answer it effectively.  Currently, your OP is missing some detail as expressed in my [last comment underneath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578320/codeigniter-3-pagination-links-and-single-post-link-throw-404/38579146?noredirect=1#comment64547440_38578320).

Comment: Thanks for help Sparky. I am still trying but not able to solve this. When I will be able to solve it, I will post the detailed issues that my code had. The URLs that I wanted to have are like http://localhost/practice/project-code-igniter/articles/1 - http://localhost/practice/project-code-igniter/articles/2 - http://localhost/practice/project-code-igniter/articles/3 for paginated pages and the single post URL like http://localhost/practice/project-code-igniter/articles/3/obcaecati-et-consequuntur-magni-maxime